# Node Discovery Issue

Tags: nodes, tor, discovery

On my node's https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/ page, clicking the "Check Node" button on the bottom of the page reports that the node associated with this IP address is up; however, at the top of the page, "Node Status" says it isn't. It seems my node is having discoverability issues with the Bitcoin network, although https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/ can ping it just fine.

Why would this be?

I've even run the node on a different network (one even supporting IPv6), and I get the same issue.

I'm thinking it may have something to do with my running bitcoin-qt with a Tor proxy, although I am explicitly supplying the "--listen" flag to bitcoin-qt.

([I've asked about this on Github](https://github.com/ayeowch/bitnodes/issues/13), but it doesn't seem to be a big in `bitnodes` but a configuration issue on my end; or perhaps the BTC network in my area just doesn't have need of more nodes?)

Comment: I'm confused - if you're running on Tor, presumably you don't want people to identify you, but you also are using --listen, which makes it substantially less anonymous. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @NickODell: I want to run Tor for outgoing connections only. This worked the first time I tried, but now Bitnodes.io says my node is down, and I haven't been discovered by the Bitcoin network since.

Comment: I just don't understand why Bitnodes.io can ping my node and detect it's there, but the Bitcoin network seems not to have discovered the node.

Comment: Very weird! Now it's working! It must've just taken a long, long time for someone to need my node, but it seems the BTC net discovered it now. I think the issue was my not opening IPv6 port 8333 (as a have an IPv6 and IPv4 firewall; only the IPv4 port 8333 was open…).

Comment: What solved it was toggling "Allow incoming connections" in bitcoin-qt GUI. For some reason the pref must've not been set properly…